# How to scroll only the iFrame but not the whole window

Tags: css, html

How do I only scroll within the iFrame, but not the whole window? I want to have text underneath the iFrame, but it's showing up when the text is longer than the iFrame. You can go to www.thesocialscreensaver.com to see what I'm talking about. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your iframe in a div, like this :

```
<div id="iframeINSIDE" style="width: 600px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden;">
<iframe name="abc" style="width: 620px; height: 200px;" src="File.html"></iframe>
```

I have checked it on Firefox and IE and works fine for both of them.You'll be able to scroll using your mousewheel and by dragging mouse pointer over the div as well.This will scroll only the iframe not whole window.

Check if it works for you.

**Newly added:** http://jsfiddle.net/TJZT4/10/

**To make iframe 100% of webpage, use:**

```
<body>
<iframe src="http://jsfiddle.net/" style="height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! But only when I know the height of the div. How do I make the div 100% of the browser window?

Comment: @Prajoth But you don't need to do that.This div will contain only the iframe and hence both of them have the same height.You can use other divs to place your text below the iframe.Check the new fiddle

Comment: I don't want to show the other text below the iFrame. I just want the iFrame to take up the whole browser window

Comment: But that's still showing the text that's behind the iFrame. I basically want to hide the text that's under the iFrame and JUST show the iFrame to the user. The iFrame has to scroll, but the text behind the iFrame should be hidden

Comment: @Prajoth You cannot hide any content on a webpage through iframe overlapping.But if you need to hide it, you can place it a div,for e.g., and hide that content.